# Print editions using metaboss on Solana

Tags: metaplex, metaboss

I'm trying to create prints from a master edition (aka original edition) using from the console. The number of prints should be limited to a fixed number.

I followed this procedure :

1. Upload the image to Arweave : `arloader upload image.jpg --with-sol --sol-keypair-path ~/.config/solana/id.json --ar-default-keypair --no-bundle`.
2. Create the json file with NFT metadata :

```
{
    "name": "name_of__the_collection",
    "symbol": "token_of_the_collection",
    "uri": "https://arweave.net/[arweave_img_tx_id]",
    "seller_fee_basis_points": 0,
    "creators": [
        {
            "address": "address_of_the_creator_of_the_collection",
            "verified": false,
            "share": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Mint the NFT :
   `metaboss mint one --keypair ~/.config/solana/id.json --nft-data-file ./metadata.json --max-editions='10'`
4. Create the all the prints :
   metaboss mint missing-editions --account address_of_the_creator_of_the_collection

I have two issues :

- On solana explorer, I have an error : error loading image
- The 4. command returns an error : Error: failed to get account data

What's wrong ?

**[edit]** Error 1 : I used uri key instead of the image in the metadata. That's why solana explorer couldn't find the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the process is good. There are some details that have to be aligned though:

Regarding the missing image:

1. You have to upload the metadata JSON file, too. This is what you reference in the mint command.
2. Your metadata is not 100% valid. E.g. you are missing the properties field. Have a look into the [Token Metadata docs](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/token-standard#the-non-fungible-standard) for more details.

Regarding `metaboss mint missing-editions`:

The Account you specify with `--account` should not be the address of the creator of the collection but instead the Master Edition Address. (Master Edition is the NFT you minted in step 3)

Since the command runs a GPA call you should add `--timeout 120` and use not use the default RPC. Otherwise you will not get results.

If it still does not work you can also run
`metaboss mint editions --next-editions 9`

Please let me know in case of any uncertainties.